# Socket.on works in cmpDidMount, but not in specific function with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get this working, but the socket.on works only inside the componentDidMount function, but I need to call it on click..This is what I got..

///Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {publicPath:config.output.publicPath}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'))

io.on('connection', socket => {
    io.emit('create', socket.id)
})

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is up!'))
```

////Create.js

```
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io ()

class Create extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={rooms: []}
        this.add = this.add.bind(this)
    }

    add() {
        socket.on('create', id => {
            this.setState({rooms: [id, ...this.state.rooms]})
            console.log(this.state.rooms);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                <button className = 'btn btn-primary create' onClick={this.add}>Create Room </button>
            </div>);
    }
}

export default Create;
```

The socket.on inside the add() function, does nothing, but when I put it inside componentDidMount it works, but not like I want it to do...Ty!

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. Since your server sends out the `create` event when the connection is made, if the `socket.on('created', ...)` is not setup on the client until you click the button, that event will not be handled.

Clicking the button and adding the socket event listener does not send an event from the client.

If you want to send a `create` event from the client to the server, you can have the server listen for an event and send back an acknowledgement when the room is created.

Server:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('create', room => {
       // create room
       socket.emit('created', roomId);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={rooms: []};
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    socket.on('created', id => {
        this.setState({rooms: [id, ...this.state.rooms]});
    });
}

...

add() {
    socket.emit('create', room);
}
```